# How do I remove acpi Warning on boot?

Tags: linux, debian, acpi

I have this message in `dmesg` log with linux 3.11.6-1 (2013-10-27) (debian version).

I wonder how to fix/remove it?

```
     [    5.098132] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000428-0x000000000000042f SystemIO conflicts with Region \PMIO 1 (20130517/utaddress-251)
     [    5.098147] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
     [    5.098156] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000530-0x000000000000053f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 1 (20130517/utaddress-251)
     [    5.098167] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
     [    5.098171] ACPI Warning: 0x0000000000000500-0x000000000000052f SystemIO conflicts with Region \GPIO 1 (20130517/utaddress-251)
     [    5.098180] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
     [    5.098186] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
     [    5.099072] ACPI Warning: 0x000000000000f040-0x000000000000f05f  SystemIO conflicts with Region \_SB_.PCI0.SBUS.SMBI 1    (20130517/utaddress-251)
     [    5.099085] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device,     you should use it instead of the native driver
```

lspci :

```
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 (rev 35)
03:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. Device 8221 (rev 05)
```

Comment: What hardware is this?

Comment: I updated my answer with lspci.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This message is about some driver being denied access to devices controlled by [the ACPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface).

By and large, my experience is that it can be safely ignored. If however you really insist on removing the warnings, I suggest you do not try booting with the option acpi=off, or maybe you try just once to see what happens. But I am afraid you might find you have troubles with wifi, bluetooth, .... However [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/139157/booting-ubuntu-12-04-with-acpi-off-grub-parameter) they say that this is mostly harmless, so no harm in trying.

One possible way to fix it is to boot with the option

```
 processor.nocst=1
```

which introduces compatibility with some old ACPI software, see [here](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_kernel/kernel_configuration/re91.html). An alternative is to use the option

```
 acpi_enforce_resources=lax
```

which obviously allows loading the drivers. This might, or not, interfere with ACPI operations.

Just for the sake of completeness (apologies if you already know this), to introduce these modifications, edit /etc/default/grub and replace

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

with

```
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi=off"
```

or whichever option you decide to try. Update grub, reboot.

Comment: I had to install by mouse because of this bug..   'acpi=off' worked for me.

Comment: Adding `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` solved it for me, thanks! (I came here via https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed.)