# lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich

Tags: ubuntu, asterisk

I use Asterisk 11 in my Ubuntu Server 14.04, but

I Have some problems with my Dahdi Driver, with conflits

Please see the `dmesg`

```
 (null)
 [   11.804460] Adding 2052092k swap on /dev/mapper/asterisk--vg-swap_1.  Priority:-1 extents:1 across:2052092k FS
 [   12.027643] systemd-udevd[327]: starting version 204
 [   12.709180] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
 [   12.715263] parport_pc 00:02: reported by Plug and Play ACPI
 [   12.715315] parport0: PC-style at 0x378 (0x778), irq 7, using FIFO      [PCSPP,TRISTATE,COMPAT,ECP]
 [   12.812123] lp0: using parport0 (interrupt-driven).
 [   12.818748] mei_me 0000:00:03.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
 [   12.877965] Floppy drive(s): fd0 is 1.44M
 [   12.922603] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000828-0x000000000000082F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000828-0x000000000000082D (\GLBC) (20140424/utaddress-254)
 [   12.922609] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000828-0x000000000000082F conflicts with OpRegion 0x000000000000082A-0x000000000000082A (\SACT) (20140424/utaddress-254)
 [   12.922613] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000828-0x000000000000082F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000828-0x0000000000000828 (\SSTS) (20140424/utaddress-254)
 [   12.922617] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
 [   12.922621] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x00000000000008B0-0x00000000000008BF conflicts with OpRegion 0x00000000000008B8-0x00000000000008BB (\GIC2) (20140424/utaddress-254)
 [   12.922624] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
 [   12.922626] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000880-0x00000000000008AF conflicts with OpRegion 0x000000000000088C-0x000000000000088F (\GIC1) (20140424/utaddress-254)
 [   12.922630] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
 [   12.922631] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
 [   13.038153] shpchp: Standard Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.4
 [   13.117951] dcdbas dcdbas: Dell Systems Management Base Driver (version 5.6.0-3.2)
 [   13.216281] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
 [   13.272719] audit: type=1400 audit(1438608815.729:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=368 comm="apparmor_parser"
 [   13.272726] audit: type=1400 audit(1438608815.729:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=368 comm="apparmor_parser"
 [   13.272732] audit: type=1400 audit(1438608815.729:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=368 comm="apparmor_parser"
 [   13.272742] audit: type=1400 audit(1438608815.729:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=367 comm="apparmor_parser"
 [   13.272749] audit: type=1400 audit(1438608815.729:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=367 comm="apparmor_parser"
 [   13.272755] audit: type=1400 audit(1438608815.729:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=367 comm="apparmor_parser"
 [   13.273205] audit: type=1400 audit(1438608815.729:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=368 comm="apparmor_parser"
 [   13.273210] audit: type=1400 audit(1438608815.729:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=368 comm="apparmor_parser"
 [   13.273227] audit: type=1400 audit(1438608815.729:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=367 comm="apparmor_parser"
 [   13.273233] audit: type=1400 audit(1438608815.729:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=367 comm="apparmor_parser"
 [   13.313689] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
 [   13.492498] kvm: disabled by bios
 [   13.674866] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
 [   13.740542] r8169 0000:03:02.0 eth1: link down
 [   13.740557] r8169 0000:03:02.0 eth1: link down
 [   13.740587] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
 [   13.769644] Velocity is AUTO mode
 [   13.784400] coretemp coretemp.0: Using relative temperature scale!
 [   13.784413] coretemp coretemp.0: Using relative temperature scale!
 [   14.093137] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 512M
 [   14.093143] checking generic (d0000000 300000) vs hw (d0000000 10000000)
 [   14.093145] fb: switching to inteldrmfb from VESA VGA
 [   14.093183] Console: switching to colour dummy device 80x25
 [   14.093311] [drm] Replacing VGA console driver
 [   14.116059] i915 0000:00:02.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
 [   14.116069] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
 [   14.116070] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
 [   14.116143] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
 [   14.117085] [drm] initialized overlay support
 [   14.164931] sound hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig: line_outs=1 (0x12/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line
 [   14.164936] sound hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=1 (0x13/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
 [   14.164939] sound hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x11/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
 [   14.164941] sound hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
 [   14.164943] sound hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
 [   14.164945] sound hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x14
 [   14.164947] sound hdaudioC0D0:      Line=0x15
 [   14.172144] input: HDA Intel Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input7
 [   14.172977] input: HDA Intel Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input8
 [   14.173069] input: HDA Intel Line Out as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input9
 [   14.174879] input: HDA Intel Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input10
 [   14.236951] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
 [   14.253794] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 160x50
 [   14.256574] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
 [   14.256576] i915 0000:00:02.0: registered panic notifier
 [   14.260148] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
 [   15.430560] EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
 [   15.500869] r8169 0000:03:02.0 eth1: link up
 [   15.500879] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready
 [   15.771290] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounting ext2 file system using the ext4 subsystem
 [   15.900036] floppy0: no floppy controllers found
 [   15.964264] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)
 [   16.222275] init: failsafe main process (708) killed by TERM signal
 [   16.567280] eth0: Link auto-negotiation speed 1000M bps full duplex
 [   21.311317] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
 [   21.363286] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (16384 buckets, 65536 max)
 [   21.562313] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
 [  492.184127] init: tty1 main process ended, respawning
```

After then I run `dahdi_cfg -vvv` my Dahdi CLI back, but the problem continue

```
 [   11.503468] kvm: disabled by bios
 [   11.507542] coretemp coretemp.0: Using relative temperature scale!
 [   11.507556] coretemp coretemp.0: Using relative temperature scale!
 [   11.518417] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:00:02.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=io+mem:owns=io+mem
 [   11.520280] [drm] initialized overlay support
 [   11.527372] dcdbas dcdbas: Dell Systems Management Base Driver (version 5.6.0-3.2)
 [   11.590852] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
 [   11.597260] audit: type=1400 audit(1438610748.051:2): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=367 comm="apparmor_parser"
 [   11.597268] audit: type=1400 audit(1438610748.051:3): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=367 comm="apparmor_parser"
 [   11.597274] audit: type=1400 audit(1438610748.051:4): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=367 comm="apparmor_parser"
 [   11.597283] audit: type=1400 audit(1438610748.051:5): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=368 comm="apparmor_parser"
 [   11.597291] audit: type=1400 audit(1438610748.051:6): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=368 comm="apparmor_parser"
 [   11.597296] audit: type=1400 audit(1438610748.051:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=368 comm="apparmor_parser"
 [   11.597749] audit: type=1400 audit(1438610748.051:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=367 comm="apparmor_parser"
 [   11.597755] audit: type=1400 audit(1438610748.051:9): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=367 comm="apparmor_parser"
 [   11.597767] audit: type=1400 audit(1438610748.051:10): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=368 comm="apparmor_parser"
 [   11.597772] audit: type=1400 audit(1438610748.051:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=368 comm="apparmor_parser"
 [   11.632943] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
 [   11.649799] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 160x50
 [   11.652579] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
 [   11.652581] i915 0000:00:02.0: registered panic notifier
 [   11.666480] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
 [   11.666586] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000828-0x000000000000082F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000828-0x000000000000082D (\GLBC) (20140424/utaddress-254)
 [   11.666592] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000828-0x000000000000082F conflicts with OpRegion 0x000000000000082A-0x000000000000082A (\SACT) (20140424/utaddress-254)
 [   11.666596] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000828-0x000000000000082F conflicts with OpRegion 0x0000000000000828-0x0000000000000828 (\SSTS) (20140424/utaddress-254)
 [   11.666600] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
 [   11.666603] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x00000000000008B0-0x00000000000008BF conflicts with OpRegion 0x00000000000008B8-0x00000000000008BB (\GIC2) (20140424/utaddress-254)
 [   11.666607] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
 [   11.666609] ACPI Warning: SystemIO range 0x0000000000000880-0x00000000000008AF conflicts with OpRegion 0x000000000000088C-0x000000000000088F (\GIC1) (20140424/utaddress-254)
 [   11.666613] ACPI: If an ACPI driver is available for this device, you should use it instead of the native driver
 [   11.666614] lpc_ich: Resource conflict(s) found affecting gpio_ich
 [   11.670169] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
 [   12.009628] r8169 0000:03:02.0 eth1: link down
 [   12.009643] r8169 0000:03:02.0 eth1: link down
 [   12.009680] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth1: link is not ready
 [   12.037647] Velocity is AUTO mode
 [   12.057030] sound hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig: line_outs=1 (0x12/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line
 [   12.057034] sound hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=1 (0x13/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
 [   12.057037] sound hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x11/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
 [   12.057039] sound hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
 [   12.057041] sound hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
 [   12.057044] sound hdaudioC0D0:      Mic=0x14
 [   12.057046] sound hdaudioC0D0:      Line=0x15
 [   12.068312] input: HDA Intel Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input7
 [   12.068434] input: HDA Intel Line as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input8
 [   12.068543] input: HDA Intel Line Out as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input9
 [   12.068648] input: HDA Intel Front Headphone as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input10
 [   12.450564] EXT4-fs (dm-0): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
 [   13.032211] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounting ext2 file system using the ext4 subsystem
 [   13.178789] EXT4-fs (sda1): mounted filesystem without journal. Opts: (null)
 [   13.373777] init: failsafe main process (695) killed by TERM signal
 [   13.522415] r8169 0000:03:02.0 eth1: link up
 [   13.522425] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth1: link becomes ready
 [   14.396050] floppy0: no floppy controllers found
 [   15.070379] eth0: Link auto-negotiation speed 1000M bps full duplex
 [   19.785242] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
 [   19.793870] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (16384 buckets, 65536 max)
 [   19.960708] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
 [  539.437379] dahdi: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
 [  539.438150] dahdi: Version: 2.10.2
 [  539.438357] dahdi: Telephony Interface Registered on major 196
 [  540.007096] wctdm24xxp 0000:03:00.0: Port 1: Installed -- AUTO FXO (FCC mode)
 [  540.007101] wctdm24xxp 0000:03:00.0: Port 2: Not installed
 [  540.007103] wctdm24xxp 0000:03:00.0: Port 3: Not installed
 [  540.007106] wctdm24xxp 0000:03:00.0: Port 4: Not installed
 [  542.480446] wctdm24xxp 0000:03:00.0: Found a Wildcard TDM: Wildcard TDM410P (0 BRI spans, 1 analog channel)
 [  542.489848] dahdi_transcode: Loaded.
 [  542.494830] INFO-xpp: revision Unknown MAX_XPDS=64 (8*8)
 [  542.494842] INFO-xpp: FEATURE: with PROTOCOL_DEBUG
 [  542.494881] INFO-xpp: FEATURE: with sync_tick() from DAHDI
 [  542.496867] INFO-xpp_usb: revision Unknown
 [  542.496947] usbcore: registered new interface driver xpp_usb
 [  542.556913] dahdi_devices pci:0000:03:00.0: local span 1 is already assigned span 1
 [  542.601238] dahdi_echocan_mg2: Registered echo canceler 'MG2'
```

How can I fix this permanent?

Comment: Check http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97974/how-do-i-remove-acpi-warning-on-boot